# asp.NET post from java

Tags: java, asp.net, android, postback, http-post

Somehow the normal httpPost does not insert the values that I send.

here is the html form:

```
<form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post" action="Login.aspx?__ufps=104203&ReturnUrl=%2fsyspower3%2fmobile%2fdefault.aspx&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEXAQUDX19QD2QPBvUTF2XiFM6IZg==">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">

<br>
<b>Username:</b><br>

<input name="ctl00$tbUsername"/><br>
<b>Password:</b><br>
<input name="ctl00$tbPwd" type="password"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ctl00$chkRememberLogin" value="0" checked>Remember Me<br>
<input name="ctl00$cmdLogin" type="submit" value="Login"/>&nbsp;
                        <input name="ctl00$cmdForgetMe" type="submit" value="Forget Me"/>
</form>
```

and this is what I am trying to do in java:

```
HttpPost httppost2 = new HttpPost(
                    "www.website.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsyspower3%2fmobile%2fdefault.aspx&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$tbUsername", "username"));
            nameValuePairs2
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$tbPwd", "password"));
            nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$chkRememberLogin", "0"));
            nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cmdLogin", "Login"));
            nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cmdForgetMe", "Forget Me"));

            httppost2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs2));

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost2);
            String responseBody4 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            System.out.println(responseBody4);
```

But the form does not change, I mean there are no values in the input as well.. Maybe that is not the way to do it. What could be the other way to accomplish form submission?

EDIT:
As i understood, do I also must post __VIEWSTATE, __EEVENTTARGET, EVENTARGUMENT values
When I check the Post values from the wireshark, they are identical to the once I post from the application... so it is a little bit confusing. I bet it is the VIEWSTATE value, that I must first get from the service and then reuse it when doing a Post

Comment: Don't understand what concerns to asp.net

Comment: web service is under asp.net, authorisation type is IIS

Answer (score 0):

please add the url params in the `NameValuePair` object (?ReturnUrl=%2fsyspower3%2fmobile%2fdefault.aspx&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1");
), also ensure that you specify the protocol being used `http://` or `https://`

Comment: why do i have to add a form action into NameValuePair?

Comment: you have created a HTTP post object & have mixed the request data between get& post..this could be the cause of the issue...
just add the params in the URL to the `List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;` & things should start to work.

Comment: is there a special way to add a string object to a NameValuePair?

Comment: not really.. its just regular constructor init with 2 args name  & value.
`NameValuePair userName = new NameValuePair("user_name","anantha.sharma");` here `user_name` is the name of the parameter and the next argument is the value.

Comment: Yes, it helped a little bit, but it was not the case that you mentioned, my solution was different, i will publish it soon